# Ubuntu keeps losing resolv.conf settings?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Every time I reboot my ubuntu server, it loses it's nameserver setting. I have to run:

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf
```

each time I reboot for it to work properly again.

I tried editing resolv.conf directly and still doesn't work properly.

Any advice?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit below file for making effect on every time when you reboot
This is head section of resolve conf which added in resolve.conf

/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head

Comment: It doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 18.04 thats working:

```
Sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo echo "nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" >> /etc/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /etc/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

But I think a better option would be to edit the /etc/network/interfaces file and configure the system correctly, including the dns you need, for example:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback 

auto enp0s3 
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

In this example the first two lines define the local interface, do not touch it, the third line says that when the computer boots up the network card enp0s3 simultaneously (you can find out the name of your network card(s) with the command ifconfig -a), the fourth line tells the enp0s3 card to listen to a dhcp server and take the data needed for its network configuration from there, and the last line tells it which dns you want to use.
If you know your network configuration, it will always be the same or you don't have a dhcp server, the file would be something like this:

```
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback 

    auto enp0s3 
    iface enp0s3 inet static
    address 10.10.5.67
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.10.5.1
    broadcast 10.10.5.255
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Another possibility is to configure the netplan file, the new default mode to manage the network from ubuntu 17.10 Artful. [Here you can see more](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2017/12/01/ubuntu-bionic-netplan) on the subject, particularly I don't like it but I am aware of its power for complex cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep settings by editing a base file.

Install resolvconf:

```sh
sudo apt-get install resolvconf
```

Edit `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`:

```sh
sudo vi /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
```

Add your nameserver:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Start resolvconf:

```sh
sudo /etc/init.d/resolvconf start
```

Check that `/etc/resolv.conf` contains the following line:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Then try to restart your server and check `/etc/resolv.conf` again.

Comment: And what if, after al that, `/etc/resolv.conf` does not contain the new entry?

Answer (score 0):

That happens because of [`resolvconf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/resolvconf.8.html). As the man page states, it allows other programs to change the DNS resolver configuration. Probably, there is a DHCP server on your network that is providing your host its IP address and the DSN servers.

You can change the DHCP configuration or force the first lines of `resolv.conf`as @sahilKataria suggested. Using your command:

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
```

Comment: Running Ubuntu 17.10, and this solution no longer works for me.  For some reason, the /etc/resolv.conf is always overwritten with 127.0.1.1 which is useless in my world.  So I must every reboot, hand edit /etc/resolv.conf --- even through "systemd-resolve --status" shows there are no issues except the latest update to ubuntu.  And I don't really want to install 'unbound' to keep this from happening.

Comment: Yeah, the new versions of Ubuntu use an embedded DNS resolver in systemd, so resolv.conf always points to 127.0.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your netplan file.  Example:

```sh
sudo vim /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
```

```yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:
      dhcp4: true # Using DHCP
      dhcp4-overrides: # Override DHCP
        use-dns: false # Disable DHCP DNS
      routes:
        - to: x.x.x.x/24
          via: x.x.x.x
          metric: 100
        - to: x.x.x.x/24
          via: x.x.x.x
          metric: 100
      nameservers: # Name Server section
          search: [somename.ddns.net] # Set your nameserver search
          addresses: [x.x.x.x] # Set your DNS Server
  version: 2
```

When you are done, run:

```sh
netplan apply
```

And make sure that you have this:

```
$ ls -ltra /etc/resolv.conf 
/etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

If `bind` is installed on the same machine:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.1.1       somename.ddns.net somename # example
bind-ipaddress  somename.ddns.net somename # example
```